# Inconsistent statistics on expression with partial index

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

[PostgreSQL 9.6.1 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 6.2.0-10) 6.2.0 20161027, 64-bit]

I have a table with timestamp ranges:

```
create table testing.test as 
select tsrange(d, null) ts from 
generate_series(timestamp '2000-01-01', timestamp '2018-01-01', interval '1 minute') s(d);
```

I need to run the following query:

```
select * 
from testing.test 
where lower(ts)> '2017-06-17 20:00:00'::timestamp and upper_inf(ts)
```

Explain analyze result for table without indexes:

```
Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..72482.26 rows=1052013 width=14) (actual time=2165.477..2239.781 rows=283920 loops=1)
  Filter: (upper_inf(ts) AND (lower(ts) > '2017-06-17 20:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 9184081
Planning time: 0.046 ms
Execution time: 2250.221 ms
```

Next I'm going to add a following partial index:

```
create index lower_rt_inf ON testing.test using btree(lower(ts)) where upper_inf(ts);    
analyze testing.test;
```

Explain analyze result for table with partial index:

```
Index Scan using lower_rt_inf on test  (cost=0.04..10939.03 rows=1051995 width=14) (actual time=0.037..52.083 rows=283920 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (lower(ts) > '2017-06-17 20:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
Planning time: 0.156 ms
Execution time: 62.900 ms
```

And:

```
SELECT null_frac, n_distinct, correlation FROM pg_catalog.pg_stats WHERE tablename = 'lower_rt_inf'

null_frac |n_distinct |correlation |
----------|-----------|------------|
0         |-1         |1           |
```

Then I create an index similar to the previous one, but without partial condition:

```
create index lower_rt_full ON testing.test using btree(lower(ts));
analyze testing.test;
```

And now the same index is used, but the cost/rows are different:

```
Index Scan using lower_rt_inf on test  (cost=0.04..1053.87 rows=101256 width=14) (actual time=0.029..58.613 rows=283920 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (lower(ts) > '2017-06-17 20:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
Planning time: 0.280 ms
Execution time: 71.794 ms
```

And a bit more:

```
select * from testing.test where lower(ts)> '2017-06-17 20:00:00'::timestamp;

Index Scan using lower_rt_full on test  (cost=0.04..3159.52 rows=303767 width=14) (actual time=0.036..64.208 rows=283920 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (lower(ts) > '2017-06-17 20:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
Planning time: 0.099 ms
Execution time: 78.759 ms
```

How can I effectively use partial indexes for expressions?

Answer (score 1):

What happens here is that the statistics on index `lower_rt_full` are used to estimate the row count, but statistics on `lower_rt_inf`, which is a partial index, aren't.

Since function are a black box for PostgreSQL, it has no idea about the distribution of `lower(ts)` and uses a bad estimate.

After `lower_rt_full` has been created and the table analyzed, PostgreSQL has a good idea about this distribution and can estimate much better. Even if the index isn't used to execute the query, it is used for query planning.

Since `upper_inf` is also a function (black box), you would get an even better estimate if you had an index `ON test (upper_inf(ts), lower(ts))`.

For an explanation why partial indexes are not considered to estimate the number of result rows, see this comment in `examine_variable` in `backend/utils/adt/selfuncs.c`, which tries to find statistical data about an expression:

> ```
>  * Has it got stats?  We only consider stats for
>  * non-partial indexes, since partial indexes probably
>  * don't reflect whole-relation statistics; the above
>  * check for uniqueness is the only info we take from
>  * a partial index.
> ```

Comment: Doesn't this render the partial JSONB indexes partially (pun) useless? E.g. `CREATE INDEX foo_jsonb ON foo (some_jsonb_column ->> 'some_field') WHERE some_jsonb_column ->> 'some_field' IS NOT NULL`. The index will be there, but row estimates will not be based on the index stats, but the hard-coded assumptions for JSONB, as if the index didn't exist?

Comment: @TuukkaMustonen Yes, exactly. I am sure there is some room for improvement, but it is tricky to figure out which statistics are useful in which case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer.
The problem in using the function in the index (lower(rt))?
Or in that the function is used in condition of partial index.

Because, if I add a separate field "latest":

```
alter table testing.test add column latest boolean;
update testing.test set latest = upper_inf(ts);
create index lower_latest_rt ON testing.test using btree(lower(ts)) where latest = true;
alter index testing.lower_latest_rt alter column lower set statistics 1000;
analyze testing.test;
```

And execute follwing query:

```
select * 
from testing.test 
where lower(ts)> '2017-06-17 20:00:00'::timestamp and latest = true
```

I have result:

```
Index Scan using lower_latest_rt on test  (cost=0.04..11406.44 rows=285833 width=23) (actual time=0.027..178.054 rows=283920 loops=1)
Index Cond: (lower(ts) > '2017-06-17 20:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
Planning time: 1.788 ms
Execution time: 188.481 ms
```